# Feature selection for SVM via Simulated Anealing

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-selection

Simulated Anealing (SA) is well-known in many optimization problem. One can read more about SA here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

I just interested in SA for feature selection using for Support Vector Machine classification, i.e we need define a subset from the input data to use as feature vectors for SVM with low classification error. So we can understand each input data subset as state s, and its energy E(s) ast the cost function for classification error.

My question is how to choose initial label set for each each vector? can it be arbitrary at the begining?

What is formula of the cost function for each state (in general, for nonlinear kernel SVM)?
And how to define the next state (choose the next subset)?